# NextJs 'npm build' and 'npm start' messes up styles

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js

I'm using NextJs for a project (Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share screenshots). When I run `'npm run dev'` for development, the website works as expected. But when I run `'npm run build'` and `'npm start'`, I see overlapping components as if something is wrong with the CSS. What could be the issue? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

There is conflicting ordering in my CSS imports, says the `mini-css-extract-plugin`. I think that's what messes the website up. But still not sure how to fix it

Comment: 1. You might need to add Appropriate CSS loaders in ur next Config(Webpack Configs)
2.  You might need to include all css references in ur _app.js
3. You might need to use Styling compatablity with SSR for the Components used in ur _document.js

Comment: Hi @Prabhu, it seems like there is conflicting css ordering during build. I think that's the real issue. But I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: Which version of nextJS you are using ? Also are u using some components library like MaterialUI ?

Comment: I'm using 9.5.5. Not using any library like MaterialUI

Answer (score 0):

I faced few css issues last week and i came across mini-css-extract-plugin, and read in article that css loaders has to be used. Here is my next.config.js check whether this would help. If you see here i have added that mini-css-extract-plugin but then i commented it out. Adding these loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'] and having all css in _app.js and proper SSR based materialUI styling in _document.js

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
// const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");


module.exports = withImages({
   target: 'serverless',
   webpack: function (config, { webpack }) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|svg|gif|md)$/,
        // use: 'raw-loader',
        // test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    })
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV),
        }
    }))
    return config
   },
  })
```

Comment: The latest NextJs is supposed to work fine without @zeith/next-css right?